# res.render Rendering failed with use populate() if i dont use it, it work

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, populate

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question with code, context, example and please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Model.find waits for a "filter" argument: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.find . That may be your problem. Pass an empty object if you want all articles.